# (NoMethodError: undefined method `email' for main:Object). Sending Welcome Email After Devise Confirm with Mandrill & Mailchimp

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, mailchimp, mandrill

I am currently overriding Devise Confirmable method to create a welcome email after a user confirms their account. Under the current setup, running UserTransactionMailer.welcome_message(self).deliver_now in the rails console results in the following error:

```
    "NoMethodError: undefined method `email' for main:Object
 from /Users/AnthonyEmtman/Documents/projects/Team_Development/kons/app/mailers/user_transaction_mailer.rb:6:in `welcome_message'"
```

Below is the `def confirm!` override in user.rb used to trigger sending the welcome_message email.

models/user.rb:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, 
         :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :zxcvbnable

  def confirm!
    send_welcome_message
    super
  end

private

  def send_welcome_message
    UserTransactionMailer.welcome_message(self).deliver_now
  end

end
```

The following files are my user_transaction_mailer.rb and base_mandrill_mailer.rb files. user_transaction_mailer.rb inherits from base_mandrill_mailer.rb so all future mailers I create will have access to the mandrill_send method, effectively reducing the amount of send code I need to write each time to the mandrill_send method.

mailers/user_transaction_mailer.rb:

```
class UserTransactionMailer < BaseMandrillMailer

  def welcome_message(user, opts={})
    options = {
      :subject => "Welcome to Kontracking",
      :email => user.email,
      :global_merge_vars => [
        {
          name: "USER_NAME",
          content: user.user_name
        }
      ],
      :template_name => "Welcome Message - Kontracking"
    }

    mandrill_send options

  end

end
```

mailers/base_mandrill_mailer.rb:

```
require "mandrill"

class BaseMandrillMailer < ApplicationMailer

  def mandrill_send(opts={})
    message = {
      :subject => "#{opts[:subject]}",
      :from_name => "Kontracking",
      :from_email => "admin@kontracking.com",
      :to =>
        [{"name" => "Some User",
          "email" => "#{opts[:email]}",
          "type" => "to"}],
      :global_merge_vars => opts[:global_merge_vars]
    }
    sending = MANDRILL.messages.send_template opts[:template_name], [], message
    rescue Mandrill::Error => e
      Rails.logger.debug("#{e.class}: #{e.message}")
      raise
  end

end
```

Running UserTransactionMailer.welcome_message(User.first).deliver_now in the rails console results in a successful delivery to my email, including the correct processing of my included merge_var of user_name to show in the email. I am inexperienced with hashes and am currently unable to figure out the solution (which is likely fairly simple) to the undefined method issue. How do I get this to work correctly?

Also, I currently have require 'mandrill' in an initializer so I should be able to delete it from the base_mandrill_mailer.rb file, correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem as the current implementation was always leaving self undefined. Altering the models/user.rb confirm method to include self and user for the message fixed the issue.

models/user.rb:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, 
         :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :zxcvbnable

  def confirm!
    send_welcome_message(self)
    super
  end

private

  def send_welcome_message(user)
    UserTransactionMailer.welcome_message(user).deliver_now
  end

end
```

All the other files were correct. I would recommend this approach for anyone looking to override the Devise mailers or specific methods and while taking advantage of the Mailchimp/Mandrill integration--especially those working on a development team. This method effectively allows you to offload the design and updating of emails to non-technical members and won't require deploying email view changes to the server (pending changes in variable names or email additions).

I've included my files for overriding Devise below.

mailers/custom_devise_mailer.rb:

```
class CustomDeviseMailer < Devise::Mailer


  def confirmation_instructions(record, token, opts={})
    options = {
      :subject => "Confirmation Instructions",
      :email => record.email,
      :global_merge_vars => [
        {
          name: "confirmation_link",
          content: user_confirmation_url(confirmation_token: token)
          }
      ],
      :template_name => "Confirmation Instructions - Kontracking"
    }

    mandrill_send options
  end


  def reset_password_instructions(record, token, opts={})
    options = {
      :subject => "Password Reset Instructions",
      :email => record.email,
      :global_merge_vars => [
        { 
          name: "password_reset_link",
          content: reset_password_url(reset_password_token: record.reset_password_token)
        }
      ],
      :template_name => "Password Reset Instructions - Kontracking"
    }

    mandrill_send options
  end


  def unlock_instructions(record, token, opts={})
    options = {
      :subject => "Account Unlock Instructions",
      :email => record.email,
      :global_merge_vars => [
        {
          name: "account_unlock_link",
          content: user_unlock_url(unlock_token: token)
        }
      ],
      :template_name => "Account Unlock Instructions - Kontracking"
    }

    mandrill_send options
  end


  def mandrill_send(opts={})
    message = {
      :subject => "#{opts[:subject]}",
      :from_name => "Kontracking",
      :from_email => "anthony.emtman@kredibleinc.com",
      :to =>
        [{"name" => "Some User",
          "email" => "#{opts[:email]}",
          "type" => "to"}],
      :global_merge_vars => opts[:global_merge_vars]
    }
    sending = MANDRILL.messages.send_template opts[:template_name], [], message
    rescue Mandrill::Error => e
      Rails.logger.debug("#{e.class}: #{e.message}")
      raise
  end


end
```

You will also need to change the mailer configuration in your Devise initializer to point to your custom mailer.

initializers/devise.rb:

```
  # ==> Mailer Configuration
  # Configure the e-mail address which will be shown in Devise::Mailer,
  # note that it will be overwritten if you use your own mailer class
  # with default "from" parameter.
  config.mailer_sender = 'john.smith@example.com'

  # Configure the class responsible to send e-mails.
  config.mailer = 'CustomDeviseMailer'
```

I also setup a simple initializer for Mandrill (I'm using the Mandrill API--files included below).

initializers/mandrill.rb:

```
require 'mandrill'

MANDRILL = Mandrill::API.new ENV['SMTP_PASSWORD']
```

config/environments/production.rb:

```
  # Do not dump schema after migrations.
  config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false

  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: ENV["SMTP_DOMAIN"] }
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address: ENV.fetch("SMTP_ADDRESS"),
    authentication: :plain
    domain: ENV.fetch("SMTP_DOMAIN"),
    enable_starttls_auto: true,
    password: ENV.fetch("SMTP_PASSWORD"),
    port: "587",
    user_name: ENV.fetch("SMTP_USERNAME")
  }
```

config/environments/development.rb:

```
  # Care if the mailer can't send.
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :test
  host = 'localhost:3000'
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: host }
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
```

config/application.yml:

SMTP_ADDRESS: smtp.mandrillapp.com
SMTP_DOMAIN: localhost
SMTP_PASSWORD: 'insert your Mandrill API key here--no quotes'
SMTP_USERNAME: 'insert your Mandrill Username here--no quotes'

I'm using figaro to manage these. I set an initializer so an error is caused if they aren't set on the server.

initializers/figaro.rb:

```
Figaro.require_keys("SMTP_ADDRESS", "SMTP_DOMAIN", 
  "SMTP_PASSWORD", "SMTP_USERNAME")
```

Let me know if you have any questions!